# 2.23 Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, appstore-approval

I'm reading many question about this problem. I'm using Phonegap for my app. 
My app download about 3mb of images. Apple reject my app and suggest to apply "do not backup attribute" to all files.[How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html)

I use this code for my 5.1 app:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
 {
      assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

      NSError *error = nil;
      BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
      if(!success){
         NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
      }
      return success;
 }
```

I put it in my AppDelegate.m . Is it correct?

Comment: I would like to add that all files are in "/var/mobile/Applications/CEEECEA6-4684-4599-B0BF-407BE2CBD3CE/Library/Caches/"

Answer (score 1):

Where are you storing the files at the moment? I guess you are you using the standard Phonegap example :

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, null);
```

A solution is using the code below for your FileSytem request, which will requets the temporary dir of your app :

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, onSuccess, onError);
```

The `LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY` on iOS would point to

```
/var/mobile/Applications/CEEECEA6-4684-4599-B0BF-407BE2CBD3CE/tmp
```

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: I use PERSISTENT because i need to have my data offline. In the tmp folder, i lost all data. I read that if i put data in Library/Caches, it will be ignored by iCloud. But Apple reject my app.

Comment: Your data in the /tmp folder will only be deleted if the device you are running runs low on data. Same for Caches...

Comment: Ok i'm modifying my path in /var/mobile/Applications/CEEECEA6-4684-4599-B0BF-407BE2CBD3CE/tmp . But, still when i check on - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage and  
check my app's storage, is still 2,3 MB.

Comment: Ok, you could use Javascript to set the com.apple.MobileBackup attribute like so parent.setMetadata(onSetMetadataSuccess, onSetMetadataFail, { "com.apple.MobileBackup": 1});

More info on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085653/phonegap-cordova-1-5-ios-do-not-back-up-file-attribute

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

```
   var DATADIR;
   var knownfiles = []; 

   function init() {
         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
   }

   function onDeviceReady() {
          window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, null);    
    }

    //Loaded my file system, now let's get a directory entry for where I'll store my crap    
    function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
         fileSystem.root.getDirectory("it.mns.dcsofficebp",{create:true},gotDir,onError);
    }

    //The directory entry callback
    function gotDir(d){
         DATADIR = d;
         var reader = DATADIR.createReader();
         localStorage.setItem("datadir",JSON.stringify(DATADIR));
         reader.readEntries(function(d){
             appReady();
         },onError);
    }

     //Result of reading my directory
     function gotFiles(entries) {
         for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                knownfiles.push(entries[i].name);
                renderPicture(entries[i].fullPath);
          }
      }
```

Where i need to put

```
parent.setMetadata(onSetMetadataSuccess, onSetMetadataFail, { "com.apple.MobileBackup": 1});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct code that is working at my side :

```
var DATADIR;
var knownfiles = []; 

function init() {
          window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, null);
}

function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log("here I am");
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("it.mns.dcsofficebp",{create:true},gotDir,false);
}
function gotDir(d){
    DATADIR = d;
    DATADIR.setMetadata(onSetMetadataSuccess, onSetMetadataFail, { "com.apple.MobileBackup": 1});
}

function onSetMetadataSuccess() {
    console.log("success setting metadata - DONE DONE DONE!")
}
function onSetMetadataFail() {
    console.log("error setting metadata")
}
```

This is my result : 2012-12-14 12:46:20.064 testproj[1779:c07] [LOG] success setting metadata - DONE DONE DONE!

Comment: I i'm trying your example. But stopping with this messages: 2012-12-14 12:32:39.676 dcsofficebp[3027:907] [INFO] Error in success callback: File2 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

Comment: Try setting `DATADIR.setMetadata(` to `d.setMetadata`

Comment: Also, `{ "com.apple.MobileBackup": 0}` needs to be `{ "com.apple.MobileBackup": 1}`.

Comment: Same error code. If could help you, i'm adding console.log(DATADIR) and it print {"isFile":false,"isDirectory":true,"name":"it.mns.dcsofficebp","fullPath":"/var/mobile/Applications/2F2629BD-BA56-4803-97C6-7520113080A8/Documents/it.mns.dcsofficebp","filesystem":null}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21136/discussion-between-ndakotabe-and-corallino)